# Permuting rows and columns of matrix according to π

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook says that Aπ is the n×n matrix obtained from A by permuting the rows and columns according to π. Then as an example matrix A [2,3,5;3,1,0;4,1,1] is shown. According to textbook Aπ1=A and Aπ2=[2,5,3;4,1,1;3,0,1].

I am wondering if the way I shuffle rows and column matters? For example if Aπ2 was in different order would that still be okay or is there a specific way of permuting the matrix that wasn't mentioned? The textbook was unclear in this regard.

Comment: It seems like $\pi$ is meant to be a permutation, in which case, yes, it's important which rows and columns are swapped. Which textbook are you using?

Comment: Well it's online course so looks like a professor created sort of his own textbook. It doesn't have a name lol just random chapters. And yes in this case it is a permutation.

Comment: Is it publicly available? Can you email the professor who wrote it? What I am trying to say is: there is enough information here to guess what is intended, but there is not enough information to retrace the calculation.